# create a dict of changes of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have to generate and update a list based on a database extract and a csv file.
I'm planning to do that using 2 pandas dataframes.

I'm able to generate the inserts (new items within the csv file based df) and the deletes (items not existing in the csv file based df) but I don't know how to generate and update the list. The dict should only contain the columns where the values are changed and the key column

The result of the operation should be something like this:

```
{'key': 10,
'column1': 'abc',
'column6': 10.8
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what the two data-frames would look like that would generate that output

Comment: And, what code you tried...

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
In [424]: df
Out[424]:
   a  b  c  d
0  7  5  1  3
1  1  8  6  1
2  9  6  5  2
3  5  5  4  2
4  7  1  4  6

In [425]: df2
Out[425]:
   a  b  c  d
0 -1  5  1 -1
1  1  8  6  1
2  9  6  5  2
3  5  5 -1  2
4  7  1  4  6

In [426]: df.index.name = 'key'

In [427]: df2.index.name = 'key'

In [430]: (df2[df2 != df]
   .....:     .dropna(how='all')
   .....:     .dropna(axis=1, how='all')
   .....:     .reset_index()
   .....:     .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1)
   .....: )
Out[430]:
0    {'a': -1.0, 'd': -1.0, 'key': 0.0}
1               {'c': -1.0, 'key': 3.0}
dtype: object
```

explanation:

```
In [441]: df2[df2 != df]
Out[441]:
       a   b    c    d
key
0   -1.0 NaN  NaN -1.0
1    NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
2    NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
3    NaN NaN -1.0  NaN
4    NaN NaN  NaN  NaN

    In [443]: df2[df2 != df].dropna(how='all')
    Out[443]:
           a   b    c    d
    key
    0   -1.0 NaN  NaN -1.0
    3    NaN NaN -1.0  NaN

In [444]: df2[df2 != df].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
Out[444]:
       a    c    d
key
0   -1.0  NaN -1.0
3    NaN -1.0  NaN
```